# How to turn off accessibility in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, accessibility, firefox-developer-tools

I was turned on accessibility service on developer tool but I cannot turn if off. The turn off button said

> Accessibility service cannot be turned off. It is used outside
>   Developer Tools.

From [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Accessibility_inspector) said that

> Once the panel content loads, you can then turn it off again using the
>   Turn Off Accessibility Features button available in the top-left
>   corner, unless you have the accessibility engine running previously to
>   operate a screenreader, in which case this button will be disabled.

The button is gray out (disabled) and there is no accessibility engine running.
How to **turn if off** or only disable via the privacy control?

[image]

Comment: read the manual: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

- Click the menu button and choose Options.
- Select the Privacy & Security panel.
- Go to the Permissions section.
- Check the Prevent accessibility services from accessing your browser checkbox.
- Restart Firefox.

From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-services

Comment: Thank you but that is **disable** via privacy control. From this link ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Accessibility_inspector ).
It said "Once the panel content loads, you can then turn it off again using the Turn Off Accessibility Features button available in the top-left corner."

But the turn off button is gray out.

Or there is only option to disable via privacy control?